# Matplotlib raises AttributeError: 'Annotation' object has no property 'text_from_points'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to run [TOBIAS](https://github.com/loosolab/TOBIAS), a collection of command-line bioinformatics tools, to analyze my sequencing data from ATAC-seq. I tried to run the last step of the pipeline, BINDetect, using the following command:

`TOBIAS BINDetect --motifs test_data/motifs.jaspar --signals test_data/Bcell_footprints.bw test_data/Tcell_footprints.bw --genome test_data/genome.fa --peaks test_data/merged_peaks_annotated.bed --peak_header test_data/merged_peaks_annotated_header.txt --outdir BINDetect_test --cond_names Bcell Tcell --cores 4`

However, I get the following error in my output:

```
2023-07-05 08:54:45 (488) [INFO]        Writing all_bindetect files
2023-07-05 08:54:45 (488) [INFO]        Creating BINDetect plot(s)
2023-07-05 08:54:45 (488) [INFO]        - Bcell / Tcell (static plot)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usrname/.local/bin/TOBIAS", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tobias/TOBIAS.py", line 154, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tobias/tools/bindetect.py", line 819, in run_bindetect
    fig = plot_bindetect(motif_list, clustering, [cond1, cond2], args)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tobias/tools/bindetect_functions.py", line 769, in plot_bindetect
    adjust_text(txts, ax=ax1, add_objects=[l], text_from_points=True, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-', color='black', lw=0.5))  #, expand_text=(0.1,1.2), expand_objects=(0.1,0.1))
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adjustText/__init__.py", line 730, in adjust_text
    ax.annotate(
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 699, in annotate
    a = mtext.Annotation(text, xy, xytext=xytext, xycoords=xycoords,
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 1885, in __init__
    Text.__init__(self, x, y, text, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 454, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 183, in __init__
    self.update(kwargs)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 231, in update
    super().update(kwargs)
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 1213, in update
    return self._update_props(
  File "/home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 1197, in _update_props
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'Annotation' object has no property 'text_from_points'
```

I tried upgrading matplotlib using `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` but I already have the latest version, 3.7.1. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib using pip (`pip uninstall matplotlib` and `pip install matplotlib`, respectively), but I still get the same error.

I'm also using the test data that the creators of TOBIAS provide when running this command, so this error is likely not resulting from an error with the files I am providing as inputs to the command.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just wanted to share that I figured out the cause of this error-- the adjusttext package needs to be downgraded to a version<0.8 (I used version 0.7.3). There's details on this in the github Issues page for TOBIAS here: https://github.com/loosolab/TOBIAS/issues/221

Answer (score 0):

if you go to bindetect_functions.py file,, use Ctrl+F to search for text_from_points=TRUE, then delete this from the code below and then re-run the same command, it should work!

adjust_text(txts, ax=ax1, add_objects=[l], text_from_points=TRUE, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-', color='black', lw=0.5))  #, expand_text=(0.1,1.2), expand_objects=(0.1,0.1))